# How to draw line within a defined x and y-axis on echart

Tags: echarts

I have a simple echart [here](https://jsfiddle.net/381510688/hff93ska/) with a simple horizontal line defined by the `yAxis` . My question is is there anyway I can confined the length of the line to a point on the `xAxis`? I want the line to end at `'2017-10-18'` instead of the end of the graph or `'2017-10-20'` [image]

I tried specifying both x and y axis at the same time, but doesn't seem to be working. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options :

### Markline

[series-line.markLine doc](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.markLine)

This is what you used in your example, but replace markline data with that :

```js
markLine: {
  data: [[
    {
      coord: [0, 0.901],
    },
    {
      coord: [4, 0.901]
    }
  ]]
}
```

`data` is a list of marklines. To declare a line with specific [[x1, y1], [x2,y2]], you'll have to define a list of points within the list of marklines (that's why there are two brackets in a row).

### Graphics

[graphic.elements-line doc](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#graphic.elements-line.type)

Otherwise graphics gives more freedom to draw anything on the graph.

```js
graphic: {
  elements: [
    {
      type: 'group',
      left: 'center',
      top: 'center',
      children: [
        {
          type: 'line',
          x: 20,
          shape: {
            x1: -250,
            y1: -100,
            x2: 10,
            y2: 40,
          },
        }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But x1,y1,x2 and y2 coordinates are in pixel. If you want it to use the series coordinates, you can use [`convertToPixel()`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.convertToPixel)

```js
myChart.convertToPixel({seriesIndex: 0}, [0,0.901])
```

### Result

[image]
In red : markline and in black : graphics
[Code](https://jsfiddle.net/1ufrzjLm/12/)